# Building Data abstraction and ADT for rectangle using "objects"

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, sicp, coordinate-system

For the below given [exercise](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/fa12/labs/lab04/lab04.html):

> Exercise 7: Abstracting Rectangles
>
> Implement a representation for rectangles in a plane. (Hint: You may want to make use of your procedures from exercise 5). Then, in terms of your constructors and selectors, create procedures that compute the perimeter and the area of a given rectangle.

where exercise 5 is:

> Consider the problem of representing line segments in a plane. Each segment is represented as a pair of points: a starting point and an ending point. Define a constructor make-segment and selectors start-segment and end-segment that define the representation of segments in terms of points. Furthermore, a point can be represented as a pair of numbers: the x coordinate and the y coordinate. Accordingly, specify a constructor make-point and selectors x-point and y-point that define this representation. Finally, using your selectors and constructors, define a procedure midpoint-segment that takes a line segment as argument and returns its midpoint (the point whose coordinates are the average of the coordinates of the endpoints)

Below is the solution:

```
# point.py
# Representation - start
from operator import sub, mul
from math import sqrt
#Constructor
def make_point(x, y):
    return (x, y)

#Selector
def x_coordinate(point):
    return point[0]

#Selector
def y_coordinate(point):
    return point[1]

#Selector
def distance_between_points(p1, p2):
    return sqrt(square(sub(p1[0],p2[0])) + square(sub(p1[1],p2[1])))

#helper for selector
def square(a):
    return mul(a, a)

#Representation - end

#Use - start

def get_x_coordinate(point):
    return x_coordinate(point)

def get_y_coordinate(point):
    return y_coordinate(point)

#Use - end
```

---

```
# segment.py
# Representation - start

from point import distance_between_points, make_point, get_x_coordinate, get_y_coordinate
#Constructor
def make_segment(point1, point2):
    return (point1, point2)

#Selector
def start_segment(lineSegment):
    return lineSegment[0]

#Selector
def end_segment(lineSegment):
    return lineSegment[1]

#Representation - end

#Use -start
def midpoint_segment(lineSegment):
    return make_point((get_x_coordinate(start_segment(lineSegment)) + get_x_coordinate(end_segment(lineSegment)))/2, (get_y_coordinate(start_segment(lineSegment)) + get_y_coordinate(end_segment(lineSegment)))/2)

def get_size(lineSegment):
    return distance_between_points(start_segment(lineSegment), end_segment(lineSegment))

#Use - end


#Driver code from user
if __name__ == "main":
    p1 = make_point(1,2)
    p2 = make_point(3, 4)
    line = make_segment(p1, p2)
    midpoint = midpoint_segment(line)
    print(midpoint)
```

---

```
# rectangle.py
# Representation - start
from point import make_point, get_x_coordinate, get_y_coordinate
from segment import get_size
from operator import sub, abs
#Constructor
def make_rectangle(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    if are_opposite_sides_equal(p1, p2, p3, p4):
        return (p1, p2, p3, p4)

#Helper for constructor
def are_opposite_sides_equal(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    if (abs(sub(get_x_coordinate(p1), get_x_coordinate(p2))) == abs(sub(get_x_coordinate(p3), get_x_coordinate(p4)))) and (abs(sub(get_y_coordinate(p2), get_y_coordinate(p3))) == abs(sub(get_y_coordinate(p1), get_y_coordinate(p4)))):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Selector
def get_length_side_segment(quadruple):
    return (quadruple[0], quadruple[1])

#Selector
def get_breadth_side_segment(quadruple):
    return (quadruple[1], quadruple[2])

#Representation - end


#Use -start
def perimeter(rectangle):
    segment1 = get_length_side_segment(rectangle)
    segment2 = get_breadth_side_segment(rectangle)
    length = get_size(segment1)
    breadth = get_size(segment2)
    return 2 * (length + breadth)

def area(rectangle):
    segment1 = get_length_side_segment(rectangle)
    segment2 = get_breadth_side_segment(rectangle)
    length = get_size(segment1)
    breadth = get_size(segment2)
    return (length * breadth)

#Use - end



#Driver code from user
if __name__ == "main":
    p1 = make_point(1, 1)
    p2 = make_point(3, 1)
    p3 = make_point(3, 3)
    p4 = make_point(1, 3)
    rectangle = make_rectangle(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    peri = perimeter(rectangle)
    area_value = area(rectangle)
    print(peri)
    print(area_value)
```

---

Here the "constructor" and "selectors" constitute the "Abstract data type" in each module holding some invariants:

Invariant1:

If we construct point `p` from x-coordinate `a` and y-coordinate `b`, then `x_coordinate(p), y_coordinate(p)` must equal `a, b`

Invariant2:

If we construct a line segment `l` from point `p1` and point `p2`, then `start_segment(l)______end_segment(l)` must equal `p1______p2`

constructor and selectors are part of representation in each module.

Data abstraction is to enforce barrier between "representation" and "Use".

My questions:

1. Based on the above points, Is the Data abstraction between 3 modules and within each module looks correct?
2. What is the behaviour condition (invariant) that constructor and selectors of rectangle supports?

Comment: Note to reviewers: This is an academic exercise in understanding OOP from the ground up, in the style of [tag:sicp], but in Python rather than Scheme. Hence, the title of the question has “objects” in quotes, and the code is not using Python's class system.

Comment: link to exercise 5 description should be included